# get "mounted" state of react-native-modal through cloneElement

Tags: react-native

I have created my own modal component based on react-native-modal with "controls" through useRef. This is my code.

```js
import React, {useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle} from 'react';
import RNModal from 'react-native-modal';

// <Modal />
export default Modal = forwardRef(({children, ...props}, ref) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
        show: () => {
        setIsVisible(true);
        },
        hide: () => {
        setIsVisible(false);
        },
        }),
        [],
    );

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {isMounted: isVisible});
    });

    return (
        <RNModal
            isVisible={isVisible}
            animationInTiming={200}
            animationOutTiming={200}
            iseNativeDriver={true}
            hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
            onBackdropPress={ref.current?.hide}
            onBackButtonPress={ref.current?.hide}
        {...props}>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </RNModal>
    );
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the "isMounted" prop through React.cloneElement. This way, I can control useEffect functions to run whenever the modal opens or closes.

The problem is: this doesn't work. When I have code like this, it doesn't work.

```js
const MyModal = forwardRef(({isMounted, ...props}, ref) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isMounted); 
    }, [isMounted]);

    return (
        <Modal ref={ref}>
            <View>...</View>
        </Modal>
    );
});
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `React.cloneElement` is working.

Perhaps your refs setup is a little muddled?

Check this code - it may be what you intended:

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  ReactNode,
} from 'react';
import {Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import RNModal from 'react-native-modal';

interface ModalProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

type ModalRefApi = {show: () => void; hide: () => void};
/**
 * Modal that exposes a ref api
 */
const ModalWithRefApi = forwardRef(({children}: ModalProps, outerRef) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  useImperativeHandle<unknown, ModalRefApi>(outerRef, () => ({
    show: () => setIsVisible(true),
    hide: () => setIsVisible(false),
  }));

  return (
    <RNModal isVisible={isVisible} onBackdropPress={() => setIsVisible(false)}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) =>
        React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement, {
          text: `PROOF THAT GETS CLONED VALUE ${i}`,
        }),
      )}
    </RNModal>
  );
});

interface MountableProps {
  text?: boolean;
}

/**
 * A child that proves its getting cloned props
 */
const MountableChild: React.FC<MountableProps> = ({
  text = '(empty by default)',
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted child');
    return function cleanUp() {
      console.log('unmounted child');
    };
  }, []);
  return <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{text}</Text>;
};

/**
 * Perhaps your intended usage?
 */
const UsingModalWithChildAndControls: React.FC = () => {
  const modalRefApi = useRef<ModalRefApi>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onPress={() => modalRefApi.current?.show()} title="show" />
      <ModalWithRefApi ref={modalRefApi}>
        <MountableChild />
        <MountableChild />
        <MountableChild />
      </ModalWithRefApi>
    </>
  );
};

export default UsingModalWithChildAndControls;
```

A few points:

- Children are unmounted when `visible:false`
- I "cloned in" the text value of the children so you can see `cloneElement` working
- I changed the RNModel prop `onBackdropPress`, before it tried to call the imperative API, which is exposed for parents. Instead I just used the internal created `setIsVisisble` state handler